# How to find score probability of classification model result in pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new to pytorch using this I've trained a image classification model, when I test the model with the image I only get label , if I want to get probability of prediction of that class how can I get that ?

```
 test_image = test_image_tensor.view(1,3,300,300)
 model.eval()
 out = model(test_image)
 ps = torch.exp(out)
 topk,topclass = ps.topk(1,dim=1)
 class_name = idx_to_class[topclass.cpu().numpy()[0][0]]
```

I'm using above code for prediction which gives only class name  , if I want label score of prediction how can I get it?

Any help or suggestion on this will be appreciated

Comment: Please note: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309642/why-is-softmax-output-not-a-good-uncertainty-measure-for-deep-learning-models#:~:text=The%20issue%20with%20many%20deep,a%20confidence%20for%20each%20label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probabilities are the softmax of the predictions:

```py
class_prob = torch.softmax(out, dim=1)
# get most probable class and its probability:
class_prob, topclass = torch.max(class_prob, dim=1)
# get class names
class_name = idx_to_class[topclass.cpu().numpy()[0][0]]
```

Comment: it gives tensor values as tensor([[0.00567,0.0433]],device='cuda:0') from this how can I get max prob?

Comment: @godzillabeast please see my edit.