# optimizer got an empty parameter list

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

If I use `optim.SGD(model_conv.fc.parameters()` I'm getting an error:

```
optimizer got an empty parameter list
```

This error is, when `model_conv.fc` is `nn.Hardtanh(...)` (also when I try to use ReLu).
But with `nn.Linear` it works fine.

What could be the reason?

```
model_conv.fc = nn.Hardtanh(min_val=0.0, max_val=1.0) #not ok --> optimizer got an empy parameter list
#model_conv.fc = nn.ReLU() #also Not OK
# num_ftrs = model_conv.fc.in_features
# model_conv.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 1) #it works fine


model_conv = model_conv.to(config.device())

optimizer_conv = optim.SGD(model_conv.fc.parameters(), lr=config.learning_rate, momentum=config.momentum) #error is here
```

Comment: You were replacing feedforward layer (with weights) with activation functions. Can you provide the model class?

Comment: @joe32140 it is pretrained resnet18. I had to change last layer to limit outputs (from 0 to 1)

Comment: You don't need to replace the fc layer. Just add activation function after model output.

Answer (score 3):

`Hardtanh` and `ReLU` are parameter-free layers but `Linear` has parameters.

Comment: Do You know what should I put int optim in this case?
optimizer_conv = optim.SGD(???what HERE ????, lr=config.learning_rate, momentum=config.momentum)

Comment: as @joe32140 said in his comment, you add the *Sigmoid* or the *Softmax* after the output of the *Linear* layer. Activation layers or squishing layers do not learn (most of them), so there is no reason to assign their parameters to an optimizer (there are no parameters).  Then, In this case, you assign the *Linear* layer's parameters to an optimizer

Comment: I want to freeze all layers except the last one. Should i do it like this?
https://files.fm/u/a9k66vgbg

And after this, add next layer with ReLu/Hardtanh ?

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure why you want to use ReLU or Hardtanh if you want to have the output in the range [0, 1]. ReLU's output has a range of [0, max(x,0)], where x is the input. Hardtanh's output ranges from -1 to 1. I recommend you to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72187725/how-to-find-score-probability-of-classification-model-result-in-pytorch

Comment: Hardtanh's is from min_val, to max_val (default -1 to 1, but in my case from 0 to 1). ReLu i =I've just given as an example, because it is more popular, but has the same problem (alternatively ReLu6, it is limited to 6).

Answer (score 0):

Activation functions are used to add non-linearity to your model which is parameter-free, so you should pass a `nn.Linear`  as a fully-connected `(FC)` layer

```
num_ftrs = model_conv.fc.in_features
model_conv.fc = nn.Sequential( list_of_FC_layers )
```

e.g

```
model_conv.fc = nn.Sequential( nn.Linear(in_features, hidden_neurons),
                               nn.Linear(hidden_neurons, out_channels) )
```

or

```
model_conv.fc = nn.Linear( in_features, out_channels)
```

`out_channels` in case of binary-classification task is `1` and in case of multi-class classification is `num_classes`

NOTE.1: for multi-class classification, Do Not use the `softmax` layer as it is done in `CrossEntropyLoss`

NOTE.2 : You can use `Sigmoid` activation for binary classification use